# Get value from a ResultSet by name

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

How can I get a value from a ResultSet by the attribute name?

**DB-Table (table):**

```
name:TEXT | age:INT | gender:INT
```

**SQL-Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='john'
```

The output is in a `java.sql.ResultSet`

How can I get a variable by column's name (name, age, gender)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please add code you already tried along with errors you got. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to ask a better received question next time.

Comment: What do you mean by *every single variable*? Do you want to get columns names like `name`, `age`, `gender`, or do you want to get values under these columns like `"Frank"` `23` `"M"`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Answer (score 5):

You can itterate over the values like this:

```
Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name='john'";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name= rs.getString("name");
            int age= rs.getInt("age");
            int gender = rs.getInt("gender");
        }
    } catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
```

Comment: @Shapci If this was the desired solution, please vote or accept the answer, so that the community can view them as solved.

Comment: @JoelGeiser the quality of the question at this point is so poor it's hard to derive much from the answer - probably better to use the comments to fix question first. Because if it doesn't get fixed it will likely end up closed anyway.

Comment: @pvg thanks for sharing; what exactly about this question makes it poor? It looks good to me and is super helpful. any thoughts?

Comment: @mtotowamkwe see the links in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862006/get-value-from-a-resultset-by-name/34862124?noredirect=1#comment57463406_34862006

Answer (score 4):

Use [ResultSetMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html):

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
```

For example:

```
...
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
   while (rs.next()) {
         int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
         for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
         {
           String columnName = metaData.getColumnName(i);
           int type = metaData.getColumnType(i);
           if (type == Types.VARCHAR || type == Types.CHAR) {
               out.print(rs.getString(columnName));
               String name= rs.getString(columnName);
           }
           if (type==Types.INTEGER){
               out.print(rs.getInt(columnName));
               int age= rs.getInt(columnName);
            }
           // ....
           // save columnName and name
         }
    }
 }
```

...